# Django: How to ensure two parameters should always be present in a query spanning foreign key?

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I have this model setup

```
class Boy(models.Model):
    number = models.IntegerField()
    name = models.CharField()

    class Meta:
       unique_together = (number, name)



class Book(models.Model):
    boy = models.ForeignKey()
    tag = models.CharField()
```

I am making the query:

books = Book.objects.update(boy__number__in=[123])

But i want to throw an error if there are multiple values return for boy_number = 123 and ask for the name.

How should I do this in Django?

Comment: `MultipleObjectsReturned` would be correct exception for this situation https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/exceptions/#multipleobjectsreturned

Answer (score 0):

Use the `count()` method:

```
boys = Boy.objects.filter(number=123)
if boys.count() > 1:
    print "There are more that one boy with number 123"
```

Or use exceptions:

```
from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist, MultipleObjectsReturned

try:
    boy = Boy.objects.get(number=123)
    print "Boy name is: ", boy.name
except ObjectDoesNotExist:
    print "There is no boys with number 123"
except MultipleObjectsReturned:
    print "There are more that one boy with number 123"
```